# WaypointMissionOperator.getAutoFlightSpeed missing

Tags: android, dji-sdk

**Context**

I need to get the current speed of the aircraft.

**Efforts**

Looking at the documentation, I can see that exists the method [WaypointMissionOperator.getAutoFlightSpeed](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/Missions/DJIWaypointMissionOperator.html?search=get%20auto%20flight%20speed&i=0&#djiwaypointv2missionoperator_getautoflightspeed_inline) which gives me that info.

**Problem**

While implementing the code, this method was missing. Was it moved, renamed or something?

**Environment**

- OS: Android
- DJI SDK version: 4.13.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `FlightControllerState` class, it contains the current status of pretty much all of the aircraft components.

Specifically, you should look at `FlightController.setStateCallback()`.  This returns current information, specifically you want to use `getVelocityX`, `getVelocityY` and `getVelocityZ`.

There are also keys for each, the documentation gives the details.

Having X, Y and Z velocities, the speed can be computed in this way:

```dart
final speed = sqrt(pow(velocity.x, 2) + pow(velocity.y, 2) + pow(velocity.z, 2));
```